# How do I disable Owl Carousel on this template

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel

I am not a web developer - but trying to do my best for a friends company. I started with a template that uses Owl Carousel, but now I've gotten very deep into it and we do not need the carousel feature.

When I try to remove the JS, the entire site breaks. I just want it to not swipe between pages (try dragging your mouse across)

https://luxusco.com/Beta/Finalindex2.html

Any help?

Comment: Not sure about the carousel issue, but that page spews a lot of errors to the console.

Comment: can you please share a code of homepage if you don't want to share then just remove the div of carousel when it may can cause problem

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-kPOfVz0kUV2XGgJwv4DNqeT7zaGTqizsuOJE_x1uyY/edit?usp=sharing @jashandeepsingh